# How to pull a docker image from a private docker registry using Helm?

Tags: docker, helm

When the default values.yaml is inspected it is not clear how to pull a private docker image.

```
# Default values for sonatype-nexus-apt.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: nginx
  tag: stable
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 80

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  path: /
  hosts:
    - chart-example.local
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #  cpu: 100m
  #  memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #  cpu: 100m
  #  memory: 128Mi

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [this Github documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md#creating-image-pull-secrets) it is possible to pull a docker image from a private docker registry:

values.yaml

```
imageCredentials:
  name: credentials-name
  registry: private-docker-registry
  username: user
  password: pass
```

templates/imagePullSecret.yaml

```
{{- define "imagePullSecret" }}
{{- printf "{\"auths\": {\"%s\": {\"auth\": \"%s\"}}}" .Values.imageCredentials.registry (printf "%s:%s" .Values.imageCredentials.username .Values.imageCredentials.password | b64enc) | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
```

templates/secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.imageCredentials.name }}
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ template "imagePullSecret" . }}
```

at the end of the templates/deployment.yaml add the following:

```
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: {{ .Values.imageCredentials.name }}
```